# How can I output text file's content line by line to a TextBox on ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm building a website in ASP.net and, in this case, I'm simply trying to read a .txt file and output it into a textbox whenever that page loads. I wrote this code so I could execute my idea:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"file_path"))
    {
        TextBox1.Text = line;
    }
}
```

However, this is not working, as when I execute the website on this page, nothing loads. There is no exception that is being called or any error.
What can I do?
If you need more details or information, please don't refrain from asking.

Edit: I think it's important to say that I've tested doing

```
TextBox1.Text = "Hello World";
```

And that worked properly.

Comment: Consider that you are looping over the lines until your reach the end of the file. At each loop you replace the previous content of the textbox with the just loaded line. If the last line of your file is an empty line you will never see any output. In any case nothing is shown in the textbox until the code exits from the page_load event. Do not expect that at each change of the box you will see the new line extracted from the file

Answer (score 1):

Well, to read the text, this works:

```
        string sFile = @"C:\TEST2\T.txt";
        string sTextData = File.ReadAllText(sFile);
        
        TextBox1.Text = sTextData;
```

And if some some reason, you LEFT OUT some HUGE MASSIVE WHOPPER detail, say like you only want the first line of text from the file?

Then this:

```
        string sFile = @"C:\TEST2\T.txt";
        string sTextData = File.ReadAllText(sFile);

        string strFirstLine = sTextData.Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())[0];

        TextBox1.Text = strFirstLine;
```

FYI:

Don't forget to set the text box to multiline if you need/want to have more then one line of text display in that box.

As pointed out, we can use this:

```
  File.ReadAllLines(sFile).FirstOrDefault();
```

however, the above still reads the whole text file.

If the text file is to be large, and we still want the first line, or wish to read + process line by line, then this is better:

```
            StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(sFile);
            int i = 0;
            while (!sR.EndOfStream)
            {
                i++;
                Debug.Print(i.ToString() + "->" + sR.ReadLine());
                if (i >= 1)
                    break;
            }
            sR.Close();
```

So, above would read line by line, and if the text file was large, or we wish to only pull + read the first line from the file? Then of course the above example is better, since only the first line (or several lines if i condition is changed) is better from a performance + io point of view.

Comment: Reading the whole file and then splitting to create an array for the whole set of lines when you need just the first line could be a very expensive error if the file happens to be very big.

Comment: I 100% agree! And you do realize that when Google, or Microsoft interviews developers for a job? They ask a bunch of questions like how big, how far, and say how would you move mount Fuji? They ask such questions since developers require a sense of how big the problem at hand is. If this is a 3 line text file, then the solution is just fine. If it is a a huge file then it is a brain dead solution. So context is everything here and without as such means very little.  In fact the poster in a delete answer DOES ask for the first line, but not in his question. So context is everything here.

Answer (score 0):

To read the first line, you can simply write this `File.ReadLines(“YourFileName”).FirstOrDefault;`

You need to use the method [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-5.0). It reruns the `string` value. And you can then assign to `Text` property.

[File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-5.0) returns `Ienumerable<string>` not `string` .

Comment: That doesn't really work because it gives me all the content of the file and I just want the first line of it.

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira check the updated answer

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira If you only want the first line, why the `foreach` loop.  Why not just `System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"file_path").First()`?

Comment: That's brilliant m8! Cheers! thx for your help

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira Also note that `ReadAllLines` returns an array of strings, each string containing a single line of the file. So, in situations where you don't just need the first or last line, you could use that to specify the index you need. Just a thought!

Comment: Ok, so $100 question. Do you know if this JUST reads the one line, or does it read full file, and THEN plucks out the one line (but, hey, so far - VERY nice and I long missed seeing that FirstOrDefault.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal is this question of me?

Comment: Well, it is "in general" to everyone here. I mean, if the text file is small, then 2 solutions posted is just fine. If the text file MIGHT be large, then the solutions posted so far are not good at all.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I think if OP is assigning to text so he might be sure that it’s small file